# How to start WPF _Project from VSPACKAGE

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2012, vspackage

i'm trying to start a WPF-Project out of a VSPACKAGE. What I'have done is so far is to create the solution with a vspackage which starts as a menue item in VS. After that i add a WPF Project to the solution and set a reference to the WPF.

Is there somebody who did something like this before ? At the moment I'm getting the error that says this..

> Fehler    1   Der Typ 'System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector' ist in
>   einer nicht referenzierten Assembly definiert. Fügen Sie einen Verweis
>   auf die Assembly 'System.Xaml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   hinzu.    C:\Users\ThesisUser\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\VSPackage_CostEstimation\VSPackage_CostEstimation\VSPackage_CostEstimationPackage.cs    85  13  VSPackage_CostEstimation

Actually I'm not sure if this is the right way to handle it. Hope you can help me..

I searched a lot for a tutorial but i could not found any.

Greetz Iki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it running. What I did was to create a WPF Project and a vspackage in the same solution. Afterthat copied the file from the wpf project into the vspackage an added the missing dependencies. I do not know if this is a good way but it works for me..

Greetz

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right and it is hard to say whether your mothod or another method is the best or not. But I found someting insteresting and want to share with you.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138567(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

from this link, if you create a VSPackage project with the option Tool Window, then a wpf control will be added automatically. This wpf control will serve as a window in visual studio.